# Alternative to Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I'm developing a c# winform application which is based on third party web API's for trading purpose. It deals with real time data coming from internet like currency rates but I'm using 8 timer in my winform to retrieve different data, application gets non-responding because of timers,

what can i do to make this application work fast and smooth?

Comment: You have to give us more information here. Are you calling the stop method at the top of your timer's tick event to make sure that the tick event is not executed again until the code within the event was executed successfully?

Comment: You realize you program it wrong - it is not non-responsive becasue of timers bu because you do all work on the UI thread.

Comment: @user65439: The Windows Forms Timer will not fire again while one tick is being executed, so you don't need to stop it. `System.Timers.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer`, however, *can* re-enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into the System.Threading.Timer instead:
[Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

> System.Threading.Timer, which executes a single callback method on a
>   thread pool thread at regular intervals. The callback method is
>   defined when the timer is instantiated and cannot be changed. Like the
>   System.Timers.Timer class, this class is intended for use as a
>   server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it
>   has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.

This link has a nice table of comparison between the different timer classes at the bottom:

[Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Sir for your Answers :), now to be specific im using  [ActiveTickFeed](http://www.activetick.com) Api to get real currency rates but because my all timers are running in UI Thread makes it non-responding, can i make System.Threading.Timer work exactly like a normal timer tick?

Answer (score 0):

Use threading. Timers (at least the ones you seem to be using) are executed in the GUI's thread. Use BackgroundWorkers (or other threading methods) instead to decouple background tasks from the GUI.

Comment: May be wrong. There is a timer class that is not in the UI thread ;)

Comment: Yes there is - but I deduced from the question that the OP is using the one that is :-). I edited my answer to make this clear though, thanks for the hint.

Comment: He could as well not and then invoke into the UI thread because this fixes the exception he otherwise gets. There is more than one error an uninformed person can do.